# How to make only the gboard keyboards word predictions visible and not the keys Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

So i have a textField and the user doesnt input keys , but the input is coming from another application that runs a MNN model. As characters are input to the textfield i want word suggestions of the gboard to be visible. I tried changing theme so that key color is same as background but failed. 
Any help would be appreciated .[image: in the below image as you can see I have enabled my word prediction as a drop down list , also Gboard is visible . I would like to edit the view in such a way that the keypad isn't visible and only words are shown .]

Comment: I have my own word prediction model too using the MultiAutoCompleteTextView . But I would like to use the benefits of GBoard.